# Specify Connection string for Entity Framework used from multiple projects

Tags: entity-framework-4, connection-string

I am currently using EntityFramework 4 with POCO objects.  The POCO objects are located in their own .net project (project.Models).  The Context is located in the DAL project (project.DAL).  I have multiple other projects that I wish to use the context/models, for Example:

project.Website

project.Webservice

project.ConsoleApplication

Question:
How do I set the Context's connection string myself?
I have noticed that the Context object automatically finds the connection string in the web.config of the website if I add it there.  Do I need to do something similiar for all the other projects?  This seems inelegant and i think i'd rather have a way to manually configure it from my own config file or something.

Thanks!
AFrieze

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a connection string as the first argument to the `ObjectContext` constructor. Read it from wherever you like and pass it explicitly, if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  Also found a nice tutorial here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx